# Internal Server Error in prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

i am using prestashop v 1.6. on payment accepted the validation.php file is not open and the Internal Server Error occurred. is some suggestion about this??

thanks advance

Comment: Its done.. its due to the permissions of files and folder that's why i having the
    problem with Internal Server Error
i change the my module permissions  777  to 755 and issue solved

Answer (score 0):

change permissions folder `777` to `755`